# Changing Coordinate string into a float

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this geo coordinate from a json file

```
 {"location": "5.554565999999999,-0.2302829999999858"}
```

I will like to know how i can convert this is into float before using it in a google map.

I will be glad if anyone can help me, thank you.

Comment: Use `.split(",")` to separate the string at the comma. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (there are many):

```
var coords = json.location.split(',');
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/azLhoshy/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var json = {
  "location": "5.554565999999999,-0.2302829999999858"
};

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var coords = json.location.split(',');
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
  map.setCenter(latLng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```